# how to displayliquid code in Jeckyll post

Tags: jekyll, blogs, liquid

Hello I am trying to make a post using jeckyll and as part of my post I would like to show some liquid code. The post should display the IF statement as part of the post text (example below).

```
{% if customer and customer.tags contains 'Wholesale'  %}
{% endif %}
```

I have tried to post this as

```
{% highlight liquid %}
   {% if customer and customer.tags contains 'Wholesale'  %}
   {% endif %}
{% endhighlight %}
```

and also

```
{% highlight markdown %}
    {% if customer and customer.tags contains 'Wholesale'  %}
    {% endif %}
{% endhighlight %}
```

but anything I try seems to be still executing the liquid code. 
Is there a way to display the IF statement my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your liquid code in {% raw %} {% endraw %} like this:

```
{% highlight liquid %}
    {% raw %}
    {% if customer and customer.tags contains 'Wholesale'  %}
    {% endif %}
    {% endraw %}
{% endhighlight %}
```

The raw tag will disable any liquid processing and output your code as desired.

Comment: yes! that was what I was missing the raw tag, thanks!